# How Do I "distribute" multiple times?

Tags: accounts, token, payments, ico, smart-contract

I can create 500,000,000 (5 hundred million) tokens.

I want to release 2,000,000 and put on SDEX (and other XLM exchanges).

Then, once sold, do a Pre-ICO and distribute 100,000,000 for this sale. Furthurmore, 8,000,000 of the Pre-ICO will go to team.

At a later time, do the Main ICO/TGE and release 160,000,000. 2,000,000 of this number will go to team.

The remaining 238,000,000 will be held for the time being.

Do I need to create 1 Issuance account, and multiple Distribution accounts (6 of them)?

Thank you,
Lee

Answer (score 3):

Technically you don't have to, although having 6 accounts for different distribution phase may be a better option if there is a need for different signatories per phase.

Comment: Thank you Tracy. I will review signatories per phase now. The initial 2M release is to fund the actual Pre-ICO, plus give me an idea of price for the Pre. I have a good idea, but want to better qualify it. The Pre (with a lockup) and Main will have different token prices, as well as the team tokens will have different lockups, so I was/am (still am but I'll figure it out - with help) confused as how to do that from just one account. Thus, my question. Again, thanks.

Comment: If you're doing lockups, that's a lot easier to do right when you have funds in different accounts. So much of this depends on your setup, so it's really hard to give you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever really *need* one distribution account.

They way assets in stellar works is that in order to issue an asset, the issuer sends it to someone.

That someone is what we call the distribution account.

After it has been issued, you can do whatever you want with it, as long as every account you want to hold your asset has a trust line.

Comment: Hi Johan, thank you for responding. I guess I don't understand how if I create 500 million tokens, and then send to one distribution account how I can then (from that single distribution account that holds 500 million) "sell" from that account to 6 different quantities at 6 different times.

Comment: Issue it per phase then - just send the exact amount of tokens needed from your issuer account to your distribution until the phase is complete..

Comment: Lee, the distribution account is just a regular account, and can send tokens to anyone.

If you want to *sell* tokens, put up an order on the DEX, or put up a webpage, and send tokens when people send XLM to you.